# NetUserAdd - Permission issue, incorrect paramater

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm using [NetUserAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370649%28VS.85%29.aspx) to add a new administrator. But I'm receiving an error that I can't figure out.

The error returned from the failing method is:

```
NET_API_STATUS: 87
PARAM_ERR: 5
```

The `NET_API_STATUS` has a value `87` which is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. And I believe the `5` is parameter 5. Which is where I'm getting confused. What parameter? My struct is identical to the one in the docs, so where is this failing?

Here's the method where it fails.

```
bool CreateAdminUser(wchar_t *username, wchar_t *password)
{
    _USER_INFO_1 ui;
    DWORD dwLevel = 1;
    DWORD dwError = 0;
    NET_API_STATUS = nStatus;

    ui.usri1_name = username;
    ui.usri1_password = password;
    ui.usri1_priv = USER_PRIV_ADMIN;
    ui.usri1_home_dir = NULL;
    ui.usri1_comment = NULL;
    ui.usri1_flags = UF_SCRIPT;
    ui.usri1_script_path = NULL;

    nStatus = NetUserAdd(NULL, dwLevel, (LPBYTE) &ui, &dwError);

    if(nStatus != NERR_Success)
    {
        printf("NET_API_STATUS: %s\nPARAM_ERR: %d\n", nStatus, dwError);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I am running the executable as admin via Run As.

**Edit**

I changed `USER_PRIV_ADMIN` to `USER_PRIV_USER` and it worked. But why am I unable to create an administrator user? I have administrator privileges. I've trued using Run As, and asking for permissions via UAC which I've included in the Manifest.

Comment: The documentation for [USER_INFO_1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371109(v=vs.85).aspx) (and USER_INFO_2) says explicitly: `When you call the NetUserAdd function, this member must be USER_PRIV_USER`. Seems you can't create administrators with this levels. Note that this is **not** stated for USER_INFO_3 and USER_INFO_4 though.

Comment: @Neitsa both USER_INFO_3 and USER_INFO_4 are valid only on servers according to the docs. I decided to try and use `NetUserSetInfo` after creating the user, but facing the same issue.

Comment: Also tried with `USER_INFO_1005`. I am getting the same error.

Comment: You can't assign admin privileges to the user that way.  Use `USER_PRIV_USER` when creating the account, and then use `NetLocalGroupAddMembers` to add the account to the Administrators group.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I ended up finding `NetLocalGroupAddMembers` last night, and got it to work. It was the only way to get it to work. Stick it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useri1.priv` member is read-only.  (I suspect that it only exists for compatibility with early versions of the old DOS-based LAN Manager, which I presume really did determine admin privilege by a flag on the account rather than by group membership.)

At any rate, the fact that it is read-only is [documented under USER_INFO_1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371109(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The level of privilege assigned to the usri1_name member. When you call the NetUserAdd function, this member must be USER_PRIV_USER. When you call the NetUserSetInfo function, this member must be the value returned by the NetUserGetInfo function or the NetUserEnum function.

The correct method for creating a new administrative user is to first create the user without admin privilege and then call [NetLocalGroupAddMembers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370436(v=vs.85).aspx) to add the user to the Administrators group.  (Or in a domain environment you might instead use [NetGroupAddUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370425(v=vs.85).aspx) to add the user to the Domain Admins group, or another group that has been given administrator privilege in your domain.)